# How to display image with URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display an image represented by the link https://www.authenticatorApi.com/pair.aspx?AppName=MyApp&AppInfo=John&SecretCode=12345678BXYT with `CachedNetworkImage` but get this `Failed to decode image` error.
However clicking the link directly will show you the qrcode image.
Please what can I do?

Comment: This link is not an image, it's an html with an image inside, so use webview or flutter_html to display it in a container.

Comment: make this an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Answer entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is not an image, it's an html with an image inside, so use webview or flutter_html to display it in a container.

*[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)*

```
class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewExample> createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}

class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable virtual display.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(title:const Text('WebView'),),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl:
            'https://www.authenticatorapi.com/pair.aspx?AppName=MyApp&AppInfo=John&SecretCode=12345678BXYT',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*[Flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)*

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
class FlutterHtmlExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlutterHtmlExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FlutterHtmlExample> createState() => FlutterHtmlExampleState();
}

class FlutterHtmlExampleState extends State<FlutterHtmlExample> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  final htmlData = r'''<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.authenticatorApi.com/pair.aspx?AppName=MyApp&AppInfo=John&SecretCode=12345678BXYT" title="W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials"></iframe>
</body>
</html>''';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(title:const Text('WebView'),),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Html(
          data: htmlData,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not an image link, use an image that end with image extension like .png or .jpeg or .jpg or any other image format

some link like this

```
https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg
```